# OrientDB Transformer 'jdbc' not found

Tags: mysql, jdbc, etl, orientdb

I've recently installed OrientDB and trying to create an import using the ETL module.

Running on OS X, i've installed orientDB using homebrew.

I've created the following ETL script:

```
{
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "begin": [
    ],
    "extractor" : {
        "row": {}
    },
    "transformers": [
        { "jdbc": {
            "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev_database",
            "userName": "root",
            "userPassword": "",
            "query": "select * from users limit 20"
          }
        },
        { "vertex": { "class": "V" } }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/ETLDemo",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}
```

Followed the instructions here: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/2.0/orientdb-etl.wiki/Import-from-DBMS.html
and installed the jdbc driver for mysql from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

and set the classpath as described.

Running the command:

```
./oetl.sh ../import_mysql.json
```

Gives the following output:

```
OrientDB etl v.2.0.2 (build @BUILD@) www.orientechnologies.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:278)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:188)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transformer 'jdbc' not found
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLComponentFactory.getTransformer(OETLComponentFactory.java:141)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parse(OETLProcessor.java:260)
    ... 2 more
```

I did manage to create a working import using a CSV file so i'm pretty sure that the database is set up correctly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan. Note that you should accept the answer instead of up vote it. Glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "config": {
        "log": "debug"
    },
    "extractor": { 
        "jdbc": {
            "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dev_database",
            "userName": "root",
            "userPassword": "",
            "query": "select * from users limit 20"
        }
    },
    "transformers" : [
        { "vertex": { "class": "V"} }
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/ETLDemo",
            "dbUser": "admin",
            "dbPassword": "admin",
            "dbAutoCreate": true,
            "tx": false,
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "dbType": "graph"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you see if this solves the problem?